# Is there a way to stop the __init__ method from executing?

Tags: python, class, methods

I have a class `Point`. Its `__init__` method checks if there is a point on turtle canvas. If it finds that it is there already, I need to prevent the init from any further execution.

```
points = []
class Point():
    def __init__(self, pen, points=points):
        self.x = pen.xcor()
        self.y = pen.ycor()
        for point in points:
            if point == (self.x, self.y, pen):
            # here, I need to stop __init__ from executing
            return True# this raises an error, but does not stop
            #the function the way I want
        points.append((self.x, self.y, pen))
        self.pen = pen
        self.get()

point1 = Point(p)
```

Here's what I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    point1 = Point(p)
TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'bool'
```

Comment: Can you just move the other code into the `else` block? Or reverse that if statement and put the code inside of it?

Comment: Do this in `__new__` instead of `__init__` to prevent the class from being instantiated at all.

Comment: This should probably raise an exception that the caller has to deal with.

Comment: Do you really want `__init__` to just *stop executing* (letting the program continue on with a weird, half-initialized Point instance), or do you want construction to *fail*? It sounds like you should have it fail and throw an exception.

Comment: @user2357112                                                                                                    
 'Do you really want __init__ to just stop executing (letting the program continue on with a weird, half-initialized Point instance)?'                                                            Yes, that's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message states, `__init__()` should return `None`, not '`bool`'. Change `return True` to a bare `return` (which is equivalent to `return None`).

```
for point in points:
    if point == (self.x, self.y, pen):
        return
```

---

> Its `__init__` method checks if there is a point on turtle canvas. If it finds that it is there already, I need to prevent the init from any further execution.

That said, the difficulty you're having is indicative of a design flaw. A point shouldn't check an external list of points and refuse to be constructed; rather, the code that's creating the point should do the check.

I would hoist the loop out of the constructor and have the caller do the check.

Comment: It depends, no? Consider a parent class that keeps track of the children that have been instantiated under an instance of the parent class.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use something like this?

```
class Point():
    def __init__(self, pen, points=points):
        self.x = pen.xcor()
        self.y = pen.ycor()
        for point in points:
            if point == (self.x, self.y, pen):
                return
        points.append((self.x, self.y, pen))
        self.pen = pen
        self.get()
```